# How to determine a (compass and straightedge) constructible number of a trigonometric equation?

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

How to determine if the solutions of
$$
\left(\frac{\pi}{12}+\frac{5}{3}x^2-x\sqrt{1-x}\right) = \arcsin x
$$
are (compass and straightedge) constructible numbers?

I got this question from my students in my calculus class: "find the implicit derivative of "
$$
\left(\frac{\pi}{12}+\frac{5}{3}x^2-x\sqrt{1-x}\right) = \arcsin x,
$$
which is a simple question, but this leaves me with the curiosity of knowing if this equation really has real solutions. Then Wolfram Alpha helped me to find 2 real solutions. But now I want to know more on these numbers: are these two number (compass and straightedge) constructible?
I am aware, having consulted the relevant Wikipedia entry, that

> "$x$ is constructible if and only if there is a closed-form expression for $x$ using only integers and the operations for addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and square roots."

but how can I apply this to the roots of the above equation?

Comment: FWIW, the numerical solutions are $x \approx 0.1578175140499398$ or $x \approx 0.7686012237382167$.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is no. Any solution of your equation must be [transcendental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number), but a number constructible with a compass and ruler [must be algebraic of degree that's a power of $\ 2\ .$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number#Algebraic_properties)

First note that the sum, product and ratio of any pair of algebraic numbers, and the square root of any non-negative algebraic number, must be algebraic, and
\begin{align}
\sin\frac{\pi}{12}&=\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2\sqrt{2}}\\
\cos\frac{\pi}{12}&=\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{2\sqrt{2}}\ .
\end{align}
Writing your equation as
$$
\frac{5x^2}{3}-x\sqrt{1-x}=\arcsin x-\frac{\pi}{12}
$$
and taking the sine of both sides gives
\begin{align}
\sin\left(\frac{5x^2}{3}-x\sqrt{1-x}\right)&=\sin\left(\arcsin x-\frac{\pi}{12}\right)\\
&=x\cos\frac{\pi}{12}-\sin\frac{\pi}{12}\cos\arcsin x\\
&=\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{2\sqrt{2}}\right)x-\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2\sqrt{2}}\right)\sqrt{1-x^2}\ .
\end{align}
Now if $\ x\ $ were algebraic, so would be $\ i\left(\frac{5x^2}{3}-x\sqrt{1-x}\right)\ ,$ $\ \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{2\sqrt{2}}\right)x-\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2\sqrt{2}}\right)\sqrt{1-x^2}\ ,$ and hence also $\ \sin\left(\frac{5x^2}{3}-x\sqrt{1-x}\right)\ .$ Also, since either $\ \cos\left(\frac{5x^2}{3}-x\sqrt{1-x}\right)=$$\,\sqrt{1-\sin^2\left(\frac{5x^2}{3}-x\sqrt{1-x}\right)}\ $ or $\ \cos\left(\frac{5x^2}{3}-x\sqrt{1-x}\right)=$$\,{-}\sqrt{1-\sin^2\left(\frac{5x^2}{3}-x\sqrt{1-x}\right)}\ $ then $\ \cos\left(\frac{5x^2}{3}-x\sqrt{1-x}\right)\ $ would be algebraic too. Thus
$$
e^{i\left(\frac{5x^2}{3}-x\sqrt{1-x}\right)}=\cos\left(\frac{5x^2}{3}-x\sqrt{1-x}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{5x^2}{3}-x\sqrt{1-x}\right)
$$
would also have to be algebraic.  But the [Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) tells us that if $\ i\left(\frac{5x^2}{3}-x\sqrt{1-x}\right)\ $ is algebraic and non-zero, then $\ e^{i\left(\frac{5x^2}{3}-x\sqrt{1-x}\right)}\ $ must be transcendental.  It therefore follows that $\ x\ $ cannot be algebraic.

Answer (score 0):

answer : it is not constructible

It`s easier to set the function to $sin(π/12+(5/3)x^2−x(√(1−x))=x$

for x to be constructible $π/12+(5/3)x^2−x(√(1−x)=x∝π$ . Therefore kx=π{k is rational}

but if kx=π then x would be trascendental which means it is not constructible.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).